# Display nth comment only when the nth value of an array is equal to true in react from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
<div class="container card">
        <p>{individualProduct.user_comments.map((eachComment) => (
                <h1 className='comment'> {eachComment} </h1>
        ))}</p>
</div>
```

By doing this I am simply printing each value in the use_comments array, however, my goal is looping through ucomments_is_approved, and once for example ucomments_is_approved[3] == true then i should show user_comments[3], i have linked below a screenshot of my data base to make it easier, i am new to javascript thus i think its very simple however i was not able to figure it out, any help would be good.

i have a given array ucomments_is_approved =[true,false,false,true]
and another array comments_users = ["good","bad", "verybad","recommended"], what I have to do is only show the comments_users when ucomments_is_approved is true so I should only show "good" and "recommended" in this case.

[FIREBASE DATABASE PICTURE SHOWING THE UCOMMENTS_IS_APPROVED AND USER_COMMENTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/froH7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container card">
        <p>{individualProduct.user_comments.map((eachComment, i) => {
              ucomments_is_approved[i] ? (
                 <h1 className='comment'> {eachComment} </h1>
               ): null
                
        })}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).